# PHP calling Salesforce SOAP API returns Id values that are all the same

Tags: php, api, soap, salesforce

I am able to log in to Salesforce through the API in php. Brief Code:

```
define('USERNAME', getenv(<myuserkey>));
define('PASSWORD', getenv(<mypwkey));
define('SECURITY_TOKEN', getenv(mytokenkey));

$sfconn = new SforceEnterpriseClient();
$sfconn->createConnection('soap/sfwsdl.xml');
$sfconn->login(USERNAME,PASSWORD . SECURITY_TOKEN);
```

Later, I call a query like this:

```
$sfqry = "SELECT Id, QualifiedApiName, NamespacePrefix, DeveloperName, MasterLabel, Label, PluralLabel, DefaultCompactLayoutId, IsCustomizable, IsApexTriggerable, IsWorkflowEnabled, IsCompactLayoutable, KeyPrefix, IsQueryable from entitydefinition";
$response = $sfconn->query($sfqry);
```

I get data results back, the usual 'object' which has a 'records' property. But in looking at the list in records, EVERY single 'Id' value is the same - e.g. 000000000AAA (15 zeros, 3 A's). Other data looks fine (e.g. QualifiedApiName and other fields are different for each record). I have used the same query in the Salesforce SOQL page and Ids are definitely different - and the other fields match what I'm getting back through my PHP query.

I have queried other objects as well, and they too seem to be returning 00000000000AAA for the Id.

In the XML file I have set up, I see the base definition of SObject as this:

```
    <!-- Base sObject (abstract) -->
    <complexType name="sObject">
        <sequence>
            <element name="fieldsToNull" type="xsd:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <element name="Id" type="tns:ID" nillable="true" />
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
```

And, of course, I see the other objects being based off that one.

I've been researching this for over 2 days. I'm afraid I may have missed something very basic since I can't find anyone else reporting this problem.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I believe you need to use "durableId" if you're looking for the id value of meta data.

Answer (score 0):

Id's in `EntityDefinition`, `FieldDefinition` are so-so, they often return a fake id. It's quite interesting topic, read [The requested resource does not exist [error] in Salesforce. What is wrong with Salesforce?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62031387/313628) if you want to know more.

Use `DurableId`, `QualifiedApiName` etc for uniqueness. What do you even need IDs for? Some url hacking attempt? That's not an official API...

Comment: My main use of id values is for synchronization (external db). I'm working an Enterprise-wide automated data dictionary (side note: way beyond table/field names/data types, but that's a different topic). As you pointed out using QualifiedApiName for EntityDefintion/FieldDefinition will be enough for me in this case. I wanted to make sure I was not missing something basic. Other data queries seem to be giving me the hoped for IDs.

Thanks for the response. At least I know I'm not insane (about these observations at least <g>).